# Collect separate models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a model `Content`. This model's objects should be the only objects the user sees.

But the objects have to handle images, videos, article etc.

I think the best solution would be to have a model for each type of content:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = ImageField()

class Article(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=100)
    text = TextField()

class Video(models.Model):
    url = URLField()
```

And the content will then be controlled with something like

```
class Content(models.Model):
    content = ForeignKey(to=?)
```

Actually a `Content` object can have more than 1 image, video, article etc. So I guess I will need to create another model `ContentSet` which may have either 1 or multiple images, videos or articles.

The advantages will be that I can categorize, have comments etc. in the `Content` object rather than handling this in all the models `Image`, `Article`, `Video`.

I need some advice on how to do this. Is it a good strategy? Will it probably be better to use `GenericRelation`? What model should my `ForeignKey` point to in my `Content` model?

I hope my idea is clear to understand. I don't know any sites doing this, so I can't refer to anything to explain it better.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the [contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) and [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also model this relationship polymorphicaly

I started to use django-polymodels becasue it is very lightweight

https://github.com/charettes/django-polymodels

You could create a content superclass

```
class Content(PolymorphicModel):
  pass    

class Image(Content):
  pass

class Article(Content):
  pass
```

and then to get all subclasses of Content

`Content.objects.all().select_subclasses()`

The documentation link I have listed above pretty much uses your exact problem as a use case, it has better examples and all the caveats involved.  I use it in production for a large website and it is extremely easy API and as long as the joins are understood performant.

Additionally, it is way cool because you can refer to content in FK and M2M relationships

Comment: Will this create the same data in both `Image` and `Content`? To me it seems a bit redundant that all data created in a model which inherits from `Content` will both be created in these models and in `Content`. What do you think about it?

Comment: Another problem arises when one wants to create a post containing both images and videos.

Comment: No `Content` and `Image` will not have the same data, they will be associated, but the fields you specify for `Image` will only be stored in your `Image` model.  I don't think your second point is a problem at all, it's one of the things PolymorhpicModel solves.  A post can refer to a `Content` using one field.  If you didn't have a polymorhpic model how would you associate posts and content? Would post have a m2m field for each `Content` type? Image, Article, and Video? What would the query look liek to get all content associated with a post? Using polymorphic simplifies that

Comment: Maybe it is the solution. How would you collect multiple images in a post? Will I have to create a model `Post`, a base_model `Content` and all my children_models `Image`, `Video` etc. And create a `ForeignKey` in `Content` refering to `Post`. And when I want to show all the different content objects related to `Post` I write `Post.content_set.all()`?

Comment: yes if content has a one to many relationship with posts, if Images can be associated with multiple posts you could use an m2m field.  Post.content_set.all() would retrieve just the `Content` instances. to retrieve the specific content types, `Image` `Video` etc you could call `post.content_set.select_subclasses()` or you could just get Images for a post `post.content_set.select_subclasses(Image)`

Comment: Thank you! :) Do you know where I can see examples on how to use polymorphic models in templates and forms?